# Practica de matrices en C++

Tags: c++, matriz

Tengo que realizar 2 matrices.

1. La primera que me imprima números aleatorios del 1 al 500.
2. La 2 que me imprima una letra ya sea A,D o P. La letra depende si la
   sumas de los MCD es mayor, menor o igual al numero que nos da la
   matriz 1.

Así lo llevo pero solo me imprime ceros. La idea es que me imprima los números y les de una categoría.

```
using namespace std;
void insertar();
void mostrar();
int letras[10][10];
int numeros[10][10];

string letra(int num){
    int suma=0;
    string letra="";
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=num/2;i++){
        if(num%1==0){
            suma=suma+i;
        }
    }
    if(suma>num){
        letra="A";
    }else if(suma<num){
        letra="D";
    }else{
        letra="P";
    }
    return letra;
}

int main() {

    int num=0;
    int i, j;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            num=1+rand()%500;
            numeros[i][j];
            letras[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout<<"Numeros Aleatorios\n"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            cout<<numeros[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Clasificacion\n"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            cout<<letras[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No estás almacenando el número en la matriz:

```
num=1+rand()%500;  // Calculas un valor
numeros[i][j];     // Pero no lo guardas
```

La solución es trivial:

```
num=1+rand()%500;
numeros[i][j] = num;
```

Claro que también puedes ahorrarte `num`. Una variable menos:

```
 numeros[i][j] = 1+rand()%500;
```

Por otro lado, si la matriz `letras` debe almacenar caracteres, deberías plantearte cambiar el tipo de la matriz. Lo suyo sería que la matriz fuese de tipo  `char`, ya que su misión es almacenar caracteres:

```
char letras[10][10];
```

Pero no te va a funcionar porque la función `letra` está devolviendo cadenas de caracteres (`std::string`), así que lo más sencillo es que `letras` sea una matriz de tipo `std::string`:

```
std::string letras[10][10];
```

Y a esta matriz le pasa exactamente lo mismo que a la anterior... no modificas sus valores iniciales en ningún momento. La solución en este caso sigue siendo trivial:

```
int num = 1 + rand() % 500; // Variable local declarada dentro del bucle
numeros[i][j] = num;
letras[i][j] = letra(num);
```

Comment: Hermano muchas gracias. Problema solucionado.